# Agenda view in orgmode sorted by tag

Tags: org-mode

I did'nt find any easy way to sort the todo list in the agenda view by tag.

My wish is to display together all todo items depending on the tag (phone calls together, mails together, ...).

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the help for the variable `org-agenda-sorting-strategy` and read the [Org Mode Manual](http://orgmode.org/org.html) especially the section on [sorting agenda views](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Presentation-and-sorting).

`org-agenda-sorting-strategy` has `tag-up` and `tag-down` sorting keys.

Answer (score 0):

Another possiblity, maybe less adequate, is to defined "multiple block" views, such as:

```
;; priority levels
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("p" . "Priorities...") t)

(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("pa" "Actions Grouped by Priority"
               (;; important things to do
                (tags-todo "+PRIORITY={A}")
                ;; medium important things to do
                (tags-todo "+PRIORITY={B}")
                ;; other things to do
                (tags-todo "+PRIORITY={C}"))) t)
```

This example is with priority cookies, but the same is valid for grouping by tags.